# How to get UIActivityIndicator to disappear once appearing?

Tags: xcode, webview, swift3, uiactivityindicatorview, activity-indicator

I currently have my app linking to a certain URL upon opening the app, and this obviously can have a delay between opening it and the webView actually loading, so I want it to display an activity indicator whenever the webView is loading, I have the following code in my ViewController.swift:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!  

@IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    webView.delegate = self

    let url = URL(string: "url to site")
    webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url!)
}

func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: UIWebView){
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView){
    activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
}
```

The activity indicator shows up from the beginning but it does not disappear once the webView loads and stays their forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is a syntax issue, you have to add an underscore in the functions.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    webView.delegate = self

    let url = URL(string: "your URL")
    webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url!))
}

func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool{

    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    return true
}

func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView: UIWebView){

    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView){

    activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
}

func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: Error){

    activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have your code organized is a bit confusing.  It appears you are declaring your `func`s *inside* the `@IBAction` function.  If this is the case, this will not work.

Try this instead

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebviewDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        ...
        webView.delegate = self

        // You should add this to your Storyboard, above the webview instead of here in the code 
        activityIndicator.center = self.view.center
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray
        // I forget the actual method name - look it up
        view.insertSubview(activityIndicator, above: webView)
    }

    @IBAction func openButton(_ sender: Any) { 
        let url = URL(string: "websiteURL")
        webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url!))
    }

    func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: UIWebView){
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView){
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    } 

    // You'll also want to add the "didFail" method
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, I just updated my question to better show what I'm looking for if you'd like to take a look, thanks!

Comment: @athill16 I would make sure that `hidesWhenStopped` is `true` as you suspect it is and implement the `didFail` delegate method.  When you place a break point in `webViewDidFinishLoad`, does it actually stop here?

Comment: I added breakpoints and they didn't trigger, but the issue was actually a syntax one which fixed most of it, so I'll update in the post. My only question left is what does the didFail method actually do? Is this in the case where the person's phone connection is so poor that the webView couldn't load?